How to get to list of recently run tasks?
If I restart VS Code and then hit Cmd+Shift+R to re-run a recent task, then I get to the following list of recently run tasks:

However I don't know how to get back there without reloading the VS Code window.
Here is the list of task commands:


Is this post helpful by chance?

Turns out you can see the recently run tasks by hitting Cmd/Ctrl + R
Tasks: Run Task
{
  "key": "cmd+r",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask"
}

